# How configure Redis Store for my production env?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

I am trying to setup Redis for a session store, but is not working at. I'm using `passport.js` and `express-flash`, and if I try run the current Redis setup, it won't work:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var redis = require("redis").createClient();
var RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);

var load = require('express-load');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var i18n = require('i18n-2');
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

If I use this session setup:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

This will show an error saying that is not safe for use in production, however the `passport.js` and the express-flash will work.

Moving on to Redis:

```
app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({
     host: 54.94.171.197, 
     port: 3000,
     client: redis
   }),
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

Should I put the static IP in the host and the 3000 in the port? I am very confused with the proper values that I need pass to the new instance.

This is my middleware:

```
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/icons/fav.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: global.config.site.host,
    port: 6379,
    client: redis
  }),
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));

// Productions Middlewares

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use('/admin', middleware.ensureAuthenticated);
  app.use(middleware.ensureHttps);
}
```

Comment: what is your concrete problem? can you show the errors?

Answer (score 1):

It’s bad practice to have your application’s configuration inside the code.

Use something like [nconf](https://github.com/flatiron/nconf) to have your configuration out of the code.

For example you could use a `config.json` file:

```
{
    "sessionSecret": "cat something",
    "redis": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 6379
    }
}
```

Configure `nconf` to look for the configuration file

```
var nconf = require('nconf');
nconf.file({ file: '/path/to/config.json' })
```

Then use the configuration in your session middleware

```
app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({
     host: nconf.get('redis:host'),
     port: nconf.get('redis:port'),
     client: redis
   }),
  secret: nconf.get('sessionSecret')
}));
```

Comment: understood, but what about the host and port @Bertrand Marron? Should i put my static ip in the host? I'm creating two servers, one http and one https, how define the port that i need insert in the port key? I am using 3000 for http and 443 for https

Comment: What? That is the configuration for your Redis host, not the web server.

Comment: Also, you should probably not listen on 443 with the node application. Instead prefer using a reverse proxy (like nginx) that will listen on 443 and do the SSL, have the communications between the reverse proxy and your node app using an arbitrary port (3000 is good), using HTTP (and not HTTPS).

Comment: hm, great!.. Thanks very much @Bertrand. This is my first real running app with node, i'm little lost hehe..

Comment: Bertrand, if i try to use Redis like you answered (i copy and paste), the passport.js and the express-session will stop and throw an error: Error: req.flash() requires sessions